# Unable to call Custom Metadata picklist field in Process Builder

Tags: process-builder, formula-field, custom-metadata

I am having an issue trying to write a formula in Process builder that will updated a text field with the picklist data from the custom metadata.

IF((CONTAINS([Object_Name_c].Field_Name__r.Name, “Implementation Management”)),false,true),$CustomMetadata.CMIS_Charge_Back_Code__mdt.Implementation_Management.Charge_Back_Code__c,
IF((CONTAINS([Object_Name__c].Field_Name__r.Name, “Boarding/QC”)), false,true),$CustomMetadata.Code__mdt.Boarding_QC.Code__c,
IF((CONTAINS([Object_Name__c].Field_Name__r.Name, “Testing Analysis”)), false,true),$CustomMetadata.Code__mdt.Testing_Analysis.Code__c,
IF((CONTAINS([Object_Name__c].Field_Name_r.Name, “Certification Testing”)), false,true),$CustomMetadata.Code__mdt.Certification_Testing.Code__c ,
IF((CONTAINS([Object_Name__c].Field_Name__r.Name, “Issue Resolution”)), false,true),$CustomMetadata.Code__mdt.Issue_Resolution.Code__c
IF((CONTAINS([Object_Name__c].Field_Name__r.Name, “Go-Live / Rollout”)), false,true),$CustomMetadata.Code__mdt.Go_Live_Rollout.Code__c , 0)))

Error: The formula expression is invalid: Syntax error

Comment: If you're getting a syntax error, it might not be the custom metadata field -- that would probably come back with an error that the field is invalid. Have you tried reformatting the formula so that you can verify the syntax is correct?

Answer (score 0):

You have "smart quote" characters instead of "straight quote" characters for your double quotes.  This happens if you copy from MS Word or web pages that are using smart quotes.  Edit your formula to use the double-quote key on your keyboard and it should work.